# UIView won't let me add Sub Views

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

So I have a view and in my viewcontoller class I try and add a subview with the following code .

```
    UIButton *test = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubView:test];
```

Nothing happens, no errors or anything. I know its being called because it is in the viewdidload method. I have a separate class were i subclass uiview could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: try giving some background color to your button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIButton *test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
test.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubView:test];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you add all the needed attributes of that button:

```
UIButton *test = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[test addTarget:self action:@selector(selector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[test setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
test.frame = CGRectMake(30, 100, 100, 100);
[view addSubview:test];
```